# Retrieve values from multiple form:input to the spring controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jstl, jsp-tags

I've a table and within that I would be having multiple rows with input text boxes. On edit, I can edit the values and these edited values have to be saved on click of Submit button. I'm having a list variable defined in my form bean and this list is used in the path of the input variable. I'm able to get the list values in my controller but it has a problem. After each iteration, the list has to be reinitialized so that the values don't keep appending in the same list. Eg : for iteration 1 I've 10 input texts and I need only those on submit. But now all values get appended to same list.

This is my jsp form :

```
<form:form id="fee" method="post" modelAttribute="clientForm" commandName = "clientForm" 
action="<%= request.getContextPath().toString()%>/addFee.do">

    <TABLE>
            <tr>
                <c:forEach var="type" items="${clientInfo}" varStatus="status">
                    <td><form:checkbox class="editable${ifeeCount}" path="includeFeeValue" value="false"/> </td>
                        <td>feeType<c:out value = "${status.index}"/></td>
                        <td>Source Fee<c:out value = "${status.index}"/></td>
                        <td><form:input class="editable${ifeeCount}" disabled="true" path="overriddenFee" /></td>
                            <td><form:errors path="overriddenFee" cssClass="error" /></td>
                </c:forEach>
            </tr>
    </TABLE>
```

This is the code in my controller to retrieve the value from the list:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/addFee.do",method = RequestMethod.POST)
protected @ResponseBody ModelAndView selectValues(@ModelAttribute("clientForm") MyForm MyForm ) throws Exception {

    MyForm = new MyForm();

    if(null != MyForm.getOverriddenFee() && MyForm.getOverriddenFee().size() > 0) {
        for(int k=0;k<MyForm.getOverriddenFee().size();k++){
            if(MyForm.getOverriddenFee().get(k) != " ")
                System.out.println("Overridden fee : "+MyForm.getOverriddenFee().get(k)+ " of "+k); //Should print only 10 values for the 10 input text boxes I've in that iteration
        }
    }
```

How do I reinitalize the list?

Answer (score -1):

You can clear the list and pass it back to the form.

Comment: How do I do that? All rows will get populated together. And I'm not initializing the list in controller or form bean. It is just accessed via path variable in the form:input.